# How to fix bind_param "Cannot pass paramete"

Tags: php, mysql

The url I use: ../accessogiornaliero.php?idplayer=45ccf2a79ec84c

accessogiornaliero.php:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE player SET lastLogin = ?,loginstreak = ? WHERE idplayer = ?');
            $query->bind_param("sis", $qdata, $loginStreak, $_GET["idplayer"]);
            $qdata = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $query->execute();
```

Error:

```
[05-May-2019 21:19:05 Europe/Rome] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference in .../accessogiornaliero.php:62
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in .../accessogiornaliero.php on line 62
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: try the initialisation first `$idplayer = $_GET["idplayer"];` and use `$query->bind_param("sis", $qdata, $loginStreak, $idplayer );` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @RaymondNijland
`[05-May-2019 21:34:00 Europe/Rome] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference in /home/ahffmqbs/public_html/magika/app/accessogiornaliero.php:63
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/ahffmqbs/public_html/magika/app/accessogiornaliero.php on line 63`
Line 63 is $qdate= ...

Comment: Ok are you sure the error is caused by that code as errors in PHP can also happen before that line number which the error has given.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The part of the code I posted to you is part of an "if". The next part of the code works perfectly. The error occurs only if that if is executed and contains the code I posted.

Comment: Can if check if mine answer makes a difference if suspect the error is because the `$qdata` DateTime object?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Ok, If I write the code in this way everything works correctly:

`$query = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE player SET lastLogin = ? WHERE idplayer = ?');
            $query->bind_param("ss", $qdata, $_GET["idplayer"]);
            $qdata = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $query->execute();`
What am I doing wrong?
In practice it seems that it is the int value that gives error.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* to tell you the truth no idea annymore hard to tell without debugging and or more code, we should see the `SHOW CREATE TABLE player` and more PHP code how everything is defined like the `$loginStreak` variable also.

Comment: loginstreak is a smallint(6) unsigned.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong? In practice it seems that it is the int value that gives error. "* the PHP error is a bit weird.. it mentions the `[05-May-2019 21:19:05 Europe/Rome]` format but talks about `parameter 3` which is indeed the `$loginStreak` variable.. unless offcource the `$loginStreak` is also containing the DateTime object you should check that with `var_dump($loginStreak); exit();` before the `$query->bind_param(..)`

Comment: You don't tell us what any of these variables are, no way to know why you can't pass them by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try assign value before

```
  $query = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE player SET lastLogin = ?,loginstreak = ? WHERE idplayer = ?');
        $qdata = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $idplayer =  $_GET["idplayer"];
        $query->bind_param("sis", $qdata, $loginStreak,  $idplayer );
        $query->execute();
```

Comment: Same error:
`[05-May-2019 21:44:33 Europe/Rome] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference in /accessogiornaliero.php:63
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /accessogiornaliero.php on line 63`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are you are trying to pass a DateTime object as reference?

`[05-May-2019 21:19:05 Europe/Rome]` on the `$qdata` variable

I think you can/should rewrite

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE player SET lastLogin = ?,loginstreak = ? WHERE idplayer = ?');
            $query->bind_param("sis", $qdata, $loginStreak, $_GET["idplayer"]);
            $qdata = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $query->execute();
```

into using MySQL's `NOW()` function which is more simple.

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE player SET lastLogin = NOW(), loginstreak = ? WHERE idplayer = ?');
            $idplayer =  $_GET["idplayer"];
            $query->bind_param("is", $loginStreak, $idplayer);                
            $query->execute();
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. If you execute the following code the table is updated correctly:
`$query = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE player SET lastLogin = ? WHERE idplayer = ?');

        $query->bind_param("ss", $qdata, $_GET["idplayer"]);

     $qdata = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

     $query->execute();`